# How do I align an element that is out of a div with other that are inside the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div and a `<select>` out of this same div.
In this way, I need to align the `<select>` element with the first column of table.

It's possible? How I do it?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#seletor').change(function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
table td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #2F5496;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-datepicker {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="seletor">
  <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
  <option value="caixa">Caixa</option>
  <option value="banco">Banco</option>
  <option value="bordero">Bordero</option>
</select>
<div style="border:1px fuchsia solid;text-align:center">
  <div id="cheque" class="content" style="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Conta Corrente Reduzida:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:44px;" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
          <a href="">
            <img src="/sistema/imagens/lupa.gif" border="0">
          </a>

          <input type="text" style="width:439px;" readonly/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Agência:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:224px;" readonly/> <span style="margin-left:37px;">Conta Corrente:</span>
          <input type="text" style="width:124px;" readonly/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nr. Cheque:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:124px;" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" /> <span style="margin-left:20px;">Série:</span>
          <input type="text" style="width:79px;" /> <span style="margin-left:20px;">Vl. Cheque:</span>
          <input type="text" style="width:124px;" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nominal a:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:424px;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Pagamento:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:74px;" class="data_browser" onKeyPress="formato(this,'DAT')" onBlur="formato(this,'DAT_LEAVE')" maxlength="10" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Obs.:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:424px;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="caixa" class="content" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Pagamento:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:74px;" class="data_browser" onKeyPress="formato(this,'DAT')" onBlur="formato(this,'DAT_LEAVE')" maxlength="10" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" /> <span>Dt. Caixa:</span>
          <input type="text" style="width:74px;" class="data_browser" onKeyPress="formato(this,'DAT')" onBlur="formato(this,'DAT_LEAVE')" maxlength="10" readonly class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Obs.:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:424px;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="banco" class="content" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Conta Corrente Reduzida:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:44px;" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
          <a href="">
            <img src="/sistema/imagens/lupa.gif" border="0">
          </a>

          <input type="text" style="width:436px;" readonly/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Agência:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:223px;" readonly/> <span style="margin-left:35px;">Conta Corrente:</span>
          <input type="text" style="width:124px;" readonly/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Pagamento:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:74px" class="data_browser" onKeyPress="formato(this,'DAT')" onBlur="formato(this,'DAT_LEAVE')" maxlength="10" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Obs.:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:424px;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="bordero" class="content" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Conta Corrente Reduzida:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:44px;" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
          <a href="">
            <img src="/sistema/imagens/lupa.gif" border="0">
          </a>

          <input type="text" style="width:436px;" readonly/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Agência:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:223px;" readonly/> <span style="margin-left:35px;">Conta Corrente:</span>
          <input type="text" style="width:124px;" readonly/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Pagamento:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:74px" class="data_browser" onKeyPress="formato(this,'DAT')" onBlur="formato(this,'DAT_LEAVE')" maxlength="10" class="number" valida="fvalnum()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Obs.:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" style="width:424px;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide some code. Possibly a fiddle (live demo)

Comment: Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/skkhgzx4/

Comment: you could use margin or position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below code to your css

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skkhgzx4/7/)

```
table td:first-child {text-align:right; width:150px;min-width:150px;}
#seletor{
    width:150px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:right;
}
```